# Javascript, Web Audio API, Oscillator.stop() has an annoying end tick noise

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

When I call the stop function of an oscillator, it ends the note with a glitchy disconnect noise.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: have u tried to add a gain node after the Oscillator and set its value to 0 before calling .stop() ? Maybe u dont need to call .stop and .start just change the gain level

Comment: I just tried that, same issue comes up.

Comment: well i think this is an pysical effect in this case. You habe your wave and this breaks to 0 so you have a higher frequenz on this point. you can try to fix it with a lowpass but you will get side effects on your signal. An other idea is to fade out

Comment: You could use a gain node and exponentialRampToValueAtTime. I wrote a bit more about it here: http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+Crack0dks has the right idea - you should add a gain node after the oscillator, set its value to 0 (this has a dezippering on the setter - i.e. it doesn't set gain to zero instantly, it ramps it very quickly) before calling stop.

HOWEVER, the reason it's not working for you trivially is because then you need to make sure the oscillator source that's going through the gain node doesn't stop instantly too - you shouldn't call stop() or stop(0), you should add a bit of time to let the gain node ramp its audio down before cutting it off.  Try "stop( audiocontext.currentTime + 0.01 )" as a starting point.  You may want to play with that last value a bit - but that's ten milliseconds, which is a good starting point.